# How to hard-wrap lines in VS Code at a specific character (NOT word wrap)

Tags: visual-studio-code, base64

I have a Base64 encoded string in a text file that is one line. In other words it contains no line breaks. I want to insert a line break every 78 characters.

None of the "wrap" extensions I have found do this, since they're geared for word wrapping and use word boundaries. Running any of these functions does nothing since the string contains no spaces or word boundaries.

I can do it on Unix using something like `fold -w 78` but this seems like something that should exist in VS Code or at least an extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of an extension that does specifically what you're asking for, but what I would do is use the [Edit with Shell Command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryu1kn.edit-with-shell) extension, and use it to run `fold -w 78` on the text in question from within VSCode.  The extension even has a "quick command" feature you can use to save that command for quick use if it is something you do often.

I use that extension fairly often for one-off transformations with things like `sort`, `sed`, `tr`, and `fmt`.  It's really handy when you know how to express the desired transformation as a shell command.